# ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> help populating a GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

So I have a layout which has a GridView. I'm trying to populate it with images. So, I fill an array with Bitmap objects and performed the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_photos);
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pix);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To my dismay, the app simply crashes when I launch it.

I'm still a noob at android, but thanks for the help!

Comment: does `view_photos.xml` contain grid view with id `gridView1`? can you post your logcat..

Comment: Can you show the code where you filled the list? Also,did you create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter? If so, use a custom row view (xml layout) and inflate it there. Then, replace "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" with "R.layout.my_custom_row_view".

Comment: For clarity here, I want to say that it was actually something else entirely making it crash, so we're good. Now I just need a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a `TextView`. You are going to have to define a custom view with an `ImageView` in it. You will then have to override the `getView` method of the `ArrayAdapter` to populate the `ImageView` with the `Bitmap`. Do a quick google for something like "android arrayadapter custom view" for tutorial or example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I discovered that when I got it to run and it displayed text xD. Ok, I'll look into making an adapter.